# Trying to setup android sdk on PC with windows XP

Tags: android, sdk

When I start setup I get this message:
XML verification failed for http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk-repository'.
Failed to fetch URL  reason: Unknown

Even when I force the download to use http nothing happens.

I get no downloads etc for the SDK. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use HTTP instead of HTTPS. It worked in my PC.